# Android ByteArrayOutputStream.write - "int off" argument, what is

Tags: java, android, http, buffer, bytearrayoutputstream

Self explanatory title, what is the int off from the android website, what does it do and why do i need it? I understand first and second argument from bytearrayoutputstream.write but not this one

from the android web:
OutputStream
Summary

void    write(byte[] b, **int off**, int len)

Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at **offset off to this output stream.**

sample code:

```
public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage() +
                    ": with " +
                    urlSpec);
        }
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`off` is short for "offset", which means the index to start copying from. That, combined with `len` (or "length"), allows you to copy an arbitrary subsequence instead of the entire source array. For example:

```
byte[] array = {1,2,3,4};
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(array, 1, 2);    // copy 2 bytes from index 1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()));
// Output:
// [2, 3]
```